# xsl: transforming each tag value

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I am creating some performance tests in JMeter and i am trying to make the testscripts as configurable as possible. for instance i use this XML:

```
<Party>
    <Id>123456</Id>
</Party>
<Agreement>
    <InternalAgreement>
        <Id>2508153801</Id>
        <AgreementType>UYTU</AgreementType>
        <AgreementTypeCombination>ULLL</AgreementTypeCombination>
        <ContractType>3</ContractType>
        <IdCombination>250851536</IdCombination>
        <ProductCode>A260</ProductCode>
    </InternalAgreement>
</Agreement>
<PartyAgreementRole>
    <PartyInternalAgreementRole>
        <PartyAgreementRoleType>AWS</PartyAgreementRoleType>
        <RoleTypeSequenceNumber>054</RoleTypeSequenceNumber>
        <EndDate>2016-11-28</EndDate>
    </PartyInternalAgreementRole>
</PartyAgreementRole>
```

I want use xslt to transform the above xml to the following (mention the different Id's):

```
<Party>
    <Id>${Id_1}</Id>
</Party>
<Agreement>
    <InternalAgreement>
        <Id>${Id_2}</Id>
        <AgreementType>${AgreementType}</AgreementType>
        <AgreementTypeCombination>${AgreementTypeCombination}</AgreementTypeCombination>
        <ContractType>${ContractType}</ContractType>
        <IdCombination>${IdCombination}</IdCombination>
        <ProductCode>${ProductCode}</ProductCode>
    </InternalAgreement>
</Agreement>
<PartyAgreementRole>
    <PartyInternalAgreementRole>
        <PartyAgreementRoleType>${PartyAgreementRoleType}</PartyAgreementRoleType>
        <RoleTypeSequenceNumber>${RoleTypeSequenceNumber}</RoleTypeSequenceNumber>
        <EndDate>${EndDate}</EndDate>
    </PartyInternalAgreementRole>
</PartyAgreementRole>
```

Thus far i have not managed to create a generic solution in xslt that does this. so far i've come up with:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()/text()[.='VN']">${PartyAgreementRoleType}</xsl:template>
```

but that's far from the solution. Can somebody direct me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand `<xsl:template match="node()/text()[.='VN']">${PartyAgreementRoleType}</xsl:template>` in your code as there doesn't seem to be any `VN` in your sample input.

However, if you want to populate `Id` elements then

```
<xsl:template match="Id">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>${Id_</xsl:text>
        <xsl:number level="any"/>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

should work and if the other elements are to be populated with their name then

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>${</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

should achieve that, so taking those templates together you get

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text>${</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
            <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Id" priority="5">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text>${Id_</xsl:text>
            <xsl:number level="any"/>
            <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

which transforms

```
<Root>
<Party>
    <Id>123456</Id>
</Party>
<Agreement>
    <InternalAgreement>
        <Id>2508153801</Id>
        <AgreementType>UYTU</AgreementType>
        <AgreementTypeCombination>ULLL</AgreementTypeCombination>
        <ContractType>3</ContractType>
        <IdCombination>250851536</IdCombination>
        <ProductCode>A260</ProductCode>
    </InternalAgreement>
</Agreement>
<PartyAgreementRole>
    <PartyInternalAgreementRole>
        <PartyAgreementRoleType>AWS</PartyAgreementRoleType>
        <RoleTypeSequenceNumber>054</RoleTypeSequenceNumber>
        <EndDate>2016-11-28</EndDate>
    </PartyInternalAgreementRole>
</PartyAgreementRole>
</Root>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Root>
<Party>
    <Id>${Id_1}</Id>
</Party>
<Agreement>
    <InternalAgreement>
        <Id>${Id_2}</Id>
        <AgreementType>${AgreementType}</AgreementType>
        <AgreementTypeCombination>${AgreementTypeCombination}</AgreementTypeCombination>
        <ContractType>${ContractType}</ContractType>
        <IdCombination>${IdCombination}</IdCombination>
        <ProductCode>${ProductCode}</ProductCode>
    </InternalAgreement>
</Agreement>
<PartyAgreementRole>
    <PartyInternalAgreementRole>
        <PartyAgreementRoleType>${PartyAgreementRoleType}</PartyAgreementRoleType>
        <RoleTypeSequenceNumber>${RoleTypeSequenceNumber}</RoleTypeSequenceNumber>
        <EndDate>${EndDate}</EndDate>
    </PartyInternalAgreementRole>
</PartyAgreementRole>
</Root>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/naZXpWR/1.

Comment: Martin, thank you for sharing your knowledge. Your solution did exactly that what i wanted to happen. And of course 'VN' should have been 'AWS'